# How do i add multiple combo boxes to JavaFX that once a item is selected the cost is display underneath?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I would like to add multiple combo boxes to JavaFX that after the user has selected an item the cost of that item will be displayed under the combo box. Also that the total cost of all the selected items will be displayed at the bottom. I know how to make one combo box that will display the cost of one item selected but can't figure out how to make multiple ones and to display the cost of everything selected

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

public class Animals extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    Button button;
    ComboBox<Animal> comboBox = new ComboBox<Animal>();
    Text textNamePrice = new Text();

    static public TextField[] tfLetters = new TextField[37];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("ComboBox ");
        button = new Button("Submit");

        comboBox = new ComboBox<Animal>();

        comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Animal>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Animal object) {
                return object.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Animal fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        });

        comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Animal("Dog", 30.12), new Animal("Cat", 23.23),
                new Animal("Bird", 15.0)));

        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            String selectionText = "Price of the " + newVal.getName() + " is : " + newVal.getPrice();

            System.out.println(selectionText);
            textNamePrice.setText(selectionText);
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(60, 60, 60, 60));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, textNamePrice, button);

        scene = new Scene(layout, 500, 350);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public class Animal {
        private String name;
        private Double price;

        public Double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Animal(String name, Double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probabls easiest to use a custom `Node` type `AnimalChooser` for displaying the `ComboBox` + price. This way the functionality for one selection+price display can be handled in one place. Also you can provide a `price` property based on the selection to sum them up from you application class.

The following example places all those `AnimalChooser`s in an `VBox` and adds a listener to the child list to add and remove listeners to/from the child list, should it be modified, which would allow you to dynamically add/remove those `AnimalChooser` to/from the `VBox` and still get a properly updated sum.

```
public class Animal {

    private final String name;
    // primitive type should be prefered here
    private final double price;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Animal(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

```
public class AnimalChooser extends VBox {

    private final ComboBox<Animal> animalCombo;
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper price;
    private final Text text;

    public AnimalChooser(ObservableList<Animal> items) {
        setSpacing(5);
        animalCombo = new ComboBox<>(items);

        // converter for using a custom string representation of Animal in the
        // combobox
        animalCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<Animal>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Animal object) {
                return object == null ? "" : object.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Animal fromString(String string) {
                if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                } else {

                    // find suitable animal from list
                    Animal animal = null;

                    for (Animal item : items) {
                        if (string.equals(item.getName())) {
                            animal = item;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    return animal;
                }
            }

        });

        text = new Text();
        price = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();

        getChildren().addAll(animalCombo, text);

        // bind price value to price property
        price.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>() {

            @Override
            public Double call() throws Exception {
                Animal animal = animalCombo.getValue();
                return animal == null ? 0d : animal.getPrice();
            }
        }, animalCombo.valueProperty()));

        // bind text to content of Text node
        text.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(animalCombo.valueProperty().isNull()).then("").otherwise(price.asString("%.2f $")));
    }

    public final double getPrice() {
        return this.price.get();
    }

    public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return this.price.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    VBox animalChoosers = new VBox(20);

    ObservableList<Animal> animals = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Animal("cat", 1000.99),
            new Animal("dog", 20.50),
            new Animal("goldfish", 15.22)
    );

    final DoubleProperty total = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    InvalidationListener listener = new InvalidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            double sum = 0d;
            for (Node n : animalChoosers.getChildren()) {
                AnimalChooser chooser = (AnimalChooser) n;
                sum += chooser.getPrice();
            }

            total.set(sum);
        }
    };

    // just in case you want to add AnimalChooser s dynamially to animalChoosers
    animalChoosers.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Node> c) {
            while (c.next()) {
                // add remove listeners updating the total
                for (Node n : c.getRemoved()) {
                    AnimalChooser chooser = (AnimalChooser) n;
                    chooser.priceProperty().removeListener(listener);
                }
                for (Node n : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                    AnimalChooser chooser = (AnimalChooser) n;
                    chooser.priceProperty().addListener(listener);
                }
            }

            listener.invalidated(null);
        }

    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        animalChoosers.getChildren().add(new AnimalChooser(animals));
    }

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(animalChoosers);
    Text totalText = new Text();
    totalText.textProperty().bind(total.asString("total: %.2f $"));

    root.setBottom(totalText);
    BorderPane.setMargin(totalText, new Insets(20));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```